# Where should I apply CSS3 transitions, on the hover element or the main element?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to use CSS3 transitions to make a `:hover` class fade in subtley rather than straight away.

I've tried apply `transition` both to the CSS for the element and also to the `:hover` css class but neither work. Where am I going wrong? How should I apply `transition` correctly?

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hha9cz72/3/)

```
#menu-main-menu a {font-size:30px;transition: zoom 5s ease;transition: color 5s ease;}
#menu-main-menu a:hover {color:#ed918b;zoom:85%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the second [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) is overriding the first one. You should combine them as follows:

```css
transition: property1 5s ease, property2 5s ease;
```

However, `zoom` [is not a animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) property. It was intended by IE and it has a limited browser support. If you want to change the scale of an element, you could use `transform: scale()` notation instead.

Therefore the declaration would be:

```css
#menu-main-menu a {
    transition: transform 5s ease, color 5s ease;
}
```

*vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity* - **[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hha9cz72/10/)**.

And to answer the initial question, in most cases it's better to apply the `transition` on the main selector rather than the `:hover` state.

Comment: I have applied it to the main selector, it still does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/hha9cz72/6/

Comment: @Francesca `zoom` was intended by IE. It is not a standard CSS property. If you want to scale an element, it's better to use CSS transform / scale notation instead.

Comment: is it also not possible to use a transition when changing colours then as I have done in my JSFiddle?

Comment: Yes it is check MY answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick example to explain this to you:

```css
div.nav1 > a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:0px;
  color:blue;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  
  }

div.nav1 > a:hover{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:10px;
  color:red;
  
  
  }

div.nav2 > a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:0px;
  color:blue;
  
  }

div.nav2 > a:hover{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:10px;
  color:red;
  transition: all 0.2s;  
  
  }

div.nav3 > a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:0px;
  color:blue;
  transition: all 2s;  
  
  }

div.nav3 > a:hover{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:10px;
  color:red;
  transition: all 0.2s;  
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav1">
<a href="a_link.html">Home</a><br />
<a href="a_link.html">About</a><br />
<a href="a_link.html">Products</a><br />
<a href="a_link.html">Contact</a><br />
</div><br />

<div class="nav2">
<a href="a_link.html">Home</a><br />
<a href="a_link.html">About</a><br />
<a href="a_link.html">Products</a><br />
<a href="a_link.html">Contact</a><br />
</div><br />

<div class="nav3">
<a href="a_link.html">Home</a><br />
<a href="a_link.html">About</a><br />
<a href="a_link.html">Products</a><br />
<a href="a_link.html">Contact</a><br />
</div>
```

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 0):

...what the above suggested, however the correct position to place it is in the element and NOT in the :hover state.

Putting it in the hover state, would trigger the smooth transition when hovering ON the element, but hovering out would be sudden because the transition wouldn't exist.